# Java Stream list operation

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

Have a `List<SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` has a date field among other fields. Using `Java Streams` was looking to obtain two lists, one containing the SomeObject instances for which the date field is non-empty while the other containing the remaining SomeObject instances with empty date fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `Collectors.partitioningBy`:

```
Map<Boolean,List<SomeObject>> partition =
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(s->s.getDate()!=null));
```

Comment: What is variable s here?

Comment: @JohnC It's the argument of the `test(SomeObject t)` method of the `Predicate<SomeObject>` functional interface passed to `Collectors.partitioningBy`. You can name it whatever you like.